# AJAX request Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, cors

I have two projects; first one is a asp.net web project and the second one is embedded http server library project.

Embedded http server project is taken from : embedded http server project

I want to save a video file from user's local to user's shared storage. I'm getting and sending file from browser using ajax request. Embedded http server is supposed to get byte array and save video on client's shared storage. I have a problem that I spent days to solve but not yet found a solution.

In Chrome it stuck on `stream.CopyTo(streamReader);`.

In Firefox and IE it gives "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error but Firefox saves file even it gives the error.

Here is the ajax request code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      function hashFile(file, chunkSize, callback) {
        var size = file.size;
        var offset = 0;
        var chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);

        SendChunk(chunk,0);

        var hashChunk = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {

                offset += chunkSize;

                if (offset < size) {
                    chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);

                    SendChunk(chunk,0);
                } 
                else if (offset > size){
                    offset -= chunkSize;
                    var newchunkSize = size - offset;

                    chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + newchunkSize);

                    SendChunk(chunk,1);
                }
            };

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
        };

        function SendChunk(chunk,end){

            if(end>0)
            {
                 var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://clientip:8080/savefileend",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: chunk
                });
            }
            else{
                var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://clientip:8080/savefile",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: chunk
                });

                ajaxRequest.done(function (e) {
                    hashChunk();

                });
                ajaxRequest.error(function (xhr) {
                    console.log(e);
                    hashChunk();
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function fileInputHandler(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var chunkSize = 10485760; // bytes
        var start = window.performance ? performance.now() : Date.now(); // DEBUG
        var onHashFile = function (digest) {
            var end = window.performance ? performance.now() : Date.now(); // DEBUG
            console.log(this.name, digest, (end - start) + 'ms'); // DEBUG
        };
        for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
            hashFile(files[i], chunkSize, onHashFile);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('file1')
  .addEventListener('change', fileInputHandler, false);
});
```

and here is the embedded server code to get the request:

```
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();

                using (var streamReader = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(streamReader);
                    videoTemp = streamReader.ToArray();
                }

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    fileStream.Write(videoTemp, 0, videoTemp.Length);
                }
```

By the way:

For IE: If I enabled "Access data sources across domains" from setting security, then it works without error in IE.

For Chrome: If I start chrome with `--disable-web-security parameter` it works without error in Chrome. But I have find the solution from code.

Comment: do you get this error only on firefox ? .. does it work on other browsers

Comment: chrome is another issue that I have to figureout , the cursor stops on stream.CopyTo(streamReader); and never goes on once I close the browser it goes on with 0 bytes and gives connection error.. IE gives same error as "Origin http://videovault not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied." but IE saves the video as chrome.

Comment: the file which has this script  should  be on the same server that you are sending the video file.this is way you get the blocked error.. if they are already on the same server change your ajax url from `http://clientip:8080/savefile` to `/savefile`

Comment: They are not on the same server, web project will be on web server (in this case on a virtual pc) and any client will have their own embedded http server to handle client responses, I know it sounds weird but I will save a video file from user's desktop to shared storage via the web project. I'm sending ajax request from client's browser and embedded http server will handle the request.

Comment: If I add this to the ajax request; `beforeSend: function (request) { request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); }` then debug stops on `stream.CopyTo(streamReader);` if I close web page it goes on but this time streamreader is empty, If I stop the http server then it gives me same error...! @sMr

Comment: Once I set the "Access data sources across domains" for IE from internet options it works without error for IE, but I couldn't make it work for Chrome and Firefox! I'm desperate , please help.. cors plugin for chrome doesn't work!

Comment: if allowing cross domain requests from browser fine for you, you can enable it for chrome  by running chrome with `--disable-web-security`  parameter

Comment: Yes, it did work for chrome. But for sure it is better to do it from code, that is not a good solution to ask customers do this for their browsers. Now that it is worked for chrome and IE from browser settings how can I do that from script or code ? Firefox is now working for now (I believe it will be fixed once I could do it from code or script)

Comment: any comment ??, I have spent days and couldn't find a solution!  I have detailed the problem.

Comment: which language and framework do you use at your server side code

Comment: c# and framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, if anyone needs it;
I have used http://nancyfx.org/ Nancy.Hosting.Self library for embedded http server, Here I was able to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to response.Headers so that I could transfer file without error.

Answer (score 0):

May be this problem is on the client side browser. For example, Google Chrome is blocked cross-origin by default. To allow it you may use plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: I have added and enabled that plugin for chrome but same as I commented on the upper post.